# Oracle SQL: Return null value when no listagg result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, listagg

I am using the following script to return some basic info. the script returns 65 lines (as expected)...

```
select unique
       trunc(li.cre_dat) cre_date,
       li.cre_usr,
       li.catnr,
       li.av_part_no,
       li.artist,
       li.title,
       li.prodtyp,
       li.packtyp,
       nvl(sp.name_for_customer,sp.name) pack_type 
from   leos_item li,
       scm_packtyp sp
where  li.cunr in ('816900','816901','816902')
and    li.item_type = 'FP'
and    li.av_part_no is null
and    trunc(li.cre_dat) >= '01-JAN-2016'
and    li.model_force_creation_idc != 'Y'
and    li.i_status != 'I'
and    li.packtyp = sp.packtyp
```

...but, when I add Listagg in to my selects, the report only returns 55 lines. 10 lines does not have a listagg result therefore are omitted from the results...

```
select unique
       trunc(li.cre_dat) cre_date,
       li.cre_usr,
       li.catnr,
       li.av_part_no,
       li.artist,
       li.title,
       li.prodtyp,
       li.packtyp,
       nvl(sp.name_for_customer,sp.name) pack_type,
       regexp_replace(listagg(nvl(bom.av_part_no,'No'), ', ')
         within group (order by bom.item_id),'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') masters
from   leos_item li,
       scm_packtyp sp,
       TABLE(leos_flatbom_pkg.GetFlatBOM(li.item_id)) bom,
       leos_item li1 
where  li.cunr in ('816900','816901','816902')
and    li.item_type = 'FP'
and    li.av_part_no is null
and    trunc(li.cre_dat) >= '01-JAN-2016'
and    li.model_force_creation_idc != 'Y'
and    li.i_status != 'I'
and    li.packtyp = sp.packtyp
and    bom.item_id = li1.item_id
and    li1.item_type = 'MT'
group by li.cre_dat,
         li.cre_usr,
         li.catnr,
         li.av_part_no,
         li.artist,
         li.title,
         li.prodtyp,
         li.packtyp,
         nvl(sp.name_for_customer,sp.name)
```

But, I also need to see these lines. is there a way to return the 10 lines where no listagg result is found. I have tried the following combinations of nullif and nvl but with no luck;

```
nullif(regexp_replace(listagg(nvl(bom.av_part_no,'No'), ', ') within group (order by bom.item_id),'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1'),'No Master')

nvl(regexp_replace(listagg(nvl(bom.av_part_no,'No'), ', ') within group (order by bom.item_id),'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1'),'No Master')
```

Comment: can you post some sample data maybe a with t construct or a small table definition with a few insert statements to show your problem. I just tried a small listagg with the hr employees table and the nulls were returned.   SELECT  department_id,
  LISTAGG(commission_pct, ', ')
  WITHIN GROUP 
  (ORDER BY hire_date, last_name) 
  from employees
  group by department_id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `LISTAGG` it is that you are performing an inner join to the `TABLE` collection expression for `leos_flatbom_pkg.GetFlatBOM(li.item_id)` and that contains zero rows so the parent row is filtered out of the results.

Replace it with a correlated sub-query something like this:

```
select unique
       trunc(li.cre_dat) cre_date,
       li.cre_usr,
       li.catnr,
       li.av_part_no,
       li.artist,
       li.title,
       li.prodtyp,
       li.packtyp,
       nvl(sp.name_for_customer,sp.name) pack_type,
       ( SELECT regexp_replace(listagg(nvl(bom.av_part_no,'No'), ', ')
                  within group (order by bom.item_id),'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1')
         FROM   TABLE( leos_flatbom_pkg.GetFlatBOM(li.item_id)) bom
                INNER JOIN leos_item li1
                ON ( bom.item_id = li1.item_id )
         WHERE  li1.item_type = 'MT'
       ) masters
from   leos_item li
       INNER JOIN
       scm_packtyp sp
       ON ( li.packtyp = sp.packtyp )
where  li.cunr in ('816900','816901','816902')
and    li.item_type = 'FP'
and    li.av_part_no is null
and    li.cre_dat >= DATE '2016-01-01'
and    li.model_force_creation_idc != 'Y'
and    li.i_status != 'I'
```

Some other points:

- Please change to using the ANSI join syntax. The old Oracle comma join syntax is difficult to know how the columns are joined (especially for outer joins) as the join condition is buried in the `WHERE` clause.
- Do not use string literals for dates (i.e. '01-JAN-2016') Oracle will do an implicit `TO_DATE()` on them using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask and if this ever changes then the query will break (without ever changing the text of the query) and it will be a pain to debug. Even worse, this is a session parameter so it is possible for one user to change it and then it will work for everyone else and not for them. Use date literals (i.e. `DATE '2016-01-01'`) or explicitly call `TO_DATE()` and supply the format mask and correct `NLS` settings.
- `li.cre_dat >= TRUNC( li.cre_dat )` so if `TRUNC( li.cre_dat ) >= DATE '2016-01-01'` is true then `li.cre_dat >= DATE '2016-01-01'` will also be true. The conculsion is you can eliminate the `TRUNC()` call.

You could also solve it using your second query and converting the `TABLE` colection expression to be an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
from   leos_item li
       scm_packtyp sp,
       TABLE(leos_flatbom_pkg.GetFlatBOM(li.item_id)) (+) bom,
       leos_item li1
where  ...
and    li.packtyp = sp.packtyp
and    li1.item_id = bom.item_id (+)
```

Comment: All points understood and taken on board. Many thanks, works perfectly!